# Passing protocol conforming type via generics not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a requirement where I have multiple `struct` conforming to *protocol* P, which I later make a collection of and execute methods like `compute()` via a `Computer` struct which helps in creating an instance of each conforming type

Why would the following code not run and what changes are required to make it run:

```
import Foundation

protocol P {
    static func instance() -> Self
}

struct A: P {
    static func instance() -> A {
        A()
    }
}

struct B: P {
    static func instance() -> B {
        B()
    }
}

struct Computer<T: P> {
    
    static func compute() -> T {
        T.instance()
    }
}

let someArray: [P.Type] = [
    A.self,
    B.self
]

for value in someArray {
    Computer<value>.compute() // ERROR: Cannot find type 'value' in scope
}
```

Comment: You can't use a variable as a generic specifier. I don't think you can make it work the way you want.

Comment: "Meta types" cannot conform to protocols. You can call static functions like `init()` or `instance()` on meta types, though: `let a = A.self.init()`. Now, it depends what you are trying to do. If you want some sort of "Factory", that seems feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the generic constraint if you pass the type as a variable to `compute` like this:

```
struct Computer {
    static func compute(with anyP: P.Type) -> P {
        anyP.instance()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the resulting type of `compute` should not be `P` explicitly, you could put the generic constraint into the method:

```
struct Computer {
    static func compute<T: P>(with anyP: T.Type) -> T {
        anyP.instance()
    }
}
```

And then call `compute` like this:

```
for value in someArray {
    let instance = Computer.compute(with: value)
    instance.doSomething()
}
```

This assumes that `P` has the method `doSomething`. If you want to access a method that is specific to `A`, you will *always* need to type cast. In the end `instance` will always be a `P` to the compiler, because it has to assume that the same code will be executed for any values within `someArray`, which is `P.Type`. No matter whether `compute` returns `P` or explicitly `T`, `instance` will still be inferred to be `P` if you place it in a loop like this.

Comment: But in this case, even if I call `Computer.compute(with: A)`, the resultant type would be P and not A which will required manual down casting in case I want to call operations of A elsewhere which are not included in P protocol. It was just for this case that I had to call a `compute` method which is a requirement of P

Comment: @user121095 in all fairness, in your own example you ignore the result of the call to `compute()`

Comment: I updated my answer to include a solution that explicitly returns the input type instead of `P`. However I'd say you still have exactly the same problem. Because either you need to manually downcast to access specific methods of `A`, or you will need to explicitly type check, because you're still iterating over a list of `P` types and in the loop you don't just know whether you're holding an `A` or a `B`.

Comment: Updated the answer again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you did not require the generic `Computer` struct, then you could directly extend P(which is functionally the same as @JanMensch's answer)

```
extension P {
    static func compute() -> Self {
        instance()
    }
}

let someArray: [P.Type] = [
    A.self,
    B.self
]

for value in someArray {
    value.compute()
}
```

but if you needed it, I don't think this would be possible. You're trying to create a new type at runtime (`Computer<A.Type>` and `Computer<B.Type>`). You cannot do that. Swift Generics only help with code duplication, AFAIK.

EDIT:

I have another roundabout solution where the `Compute<>` is transient in a extension on P. However, I'm not sure if this would fit your use case without additional information, though.

```
extension P {
    static func computeImpl() -> Self {
        Computer<Self>.compute()
    }
}

struct Computer<T: P> {
    static func compute() -> T {
        print(T.self)
        return T.instance()
    }
}

let someArray: [P.Type] = [
    A.self,
    B.self
]

for value in someArray {
    value.computeImpl()
}
```